# Different versions LibreOffice applications vs. entire suite within Ubuntu Software

Tags: 22.04, software-center, libreoffice

When I search for LibreOffice in Ubuntu software, I see the individual applications as well as the the whole LibreOffice suite or whatever. The individual applications are outdated (version 7.3.7), but the version of the entire suite is version 7.5.4.2 (This is the version I have installed). This doesn't seem like a good experience from a user perspective, the suite is the last item in the list of applications. The preinstalled versions of LibreOffice are these outdated versions. Is this an issue with Ubuntu software, LibreOffice, or something else? I would expect all of them to be the same version.

List of applications:

[image: List of applications]

LibreOffice Writer:

[image: libre office writer]

LibreOffice suite:

[image: libre office suite]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice 7.3.7 = Ubuntu 22.04 using apt.

The version of LibreOffice in the Ubuntu apt/deb repositories is locked and won't be changed for the entire life of the release. Ubuntu Pro 22.04 ESM users in 2031 will still be offered LibreOffice 7.3.7.

- See [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283) for the long explanation why.

Folks who regularly want newer software should generally not be using LTS releases, which are *always* locked to older versions (well, it was new at release time...years ago). The six-month releases of Ubuntu offer lots of newer software. That's their purpose.

Folks who want to avoid the frustration of constant updates and changes *except* they DO want a version-bump to LibreOffice should use the LTS release with the LibreOffice snap instead of the deb.

Enterprise users who want to stick with a single unchanging workflow, and DON'T want version bumps that cause disruption should use the LTS release and the consistent set of compatible software therein.